# Unable to create dataframe using SQLContext object in spark2.2

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using `spark 2.2 version` on Microsoft Windows 7. I want to load csv file in one variable to perform SQL related actions later on but unable to do so. I referred accepted answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205991/how-to-read-csv-file-using-spark-shell)  link but of no use. I followed below steps for creating `SparkContext` object and `SQLContext` object:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext  
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf  
val sc=SparkContext.getOrCreate() // Creating spark context object 
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc) // Creating SQL object for query related tasks
```

Objects are created successfully but when I execute below code it throws an error which can't be posted here.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("D://ResourceData.csv")
```

And when I try something like `df.show(2)` it says that df was not found. I tried databricks solution for loading CSV from the attached link. It downloads the packages but doesn't load csv file. So how can I rectify my problem?? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: spark 2.x has SparkSession as entry point..

Comment: I am able to create objects sir. I tried playing with sc object and it works perfectly

Comment: as @undefined_variable suggested, you can use `SparkSession` to do these. If you are running `spark-shell` you will get `SparkSession` in `spark` variable.

Comment: I already tried this : import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder.
    master("local")
    .appName("spark session example")
    .getOrCreate() @VipinGS

Comment: are you using spark-shell?

Comment: i replaced my version with 2.2.1. There is some problem with 2.2.0 version now i am able to getting spark variable automatically what should i do now

Comment: check this post to [load CSV as DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39533431/1592191)

Comment: How to load local file?? because every reference shows path for hdfs but when i execute using local path it throws me a long error @mrsrinivas

Comment: just prefix `"file://"` to the path. make sure you are running the code in single machine only.

Comment: yes you mean i should enter "file://D://ResourceData.csv" . Is it correct path to load data directly from d drive

Comment: How are you running spark, spark-shell ?

Comment: i open my cmd and enter spark-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem for loading local file in dataframe using `1.6 version` in `cloudera VM` with the help of below code:

```
1) sudo spark-shell --jars /usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-csv_2.10-1.5.0.jar,/usr/lib/spark/lib/commons-csv-1.5.jar,/usr/lib/spark/lib/univocity-parsers-1.5.1.jar  

2) val df1 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true" ).option("parserLib", "univocity").load("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/ResourceData.csv")
```

**NOTE**: `sc` and `sqlContext` variables are automatically created
But there are many improvements in the latest version i.e 2.2.1 which I am unable to use because metastore_db doesn't gets created in windows 7. I ll post a new question regarding the same.

Answer (score 2):

In reference with your comment that you are able to access `SparkSession` variable, then follow below steps to process your csv file using **SparkSQL**.

> Spark SQL is a Spark module for structured data processing.

---

There are mainly two abstractions - **Dataset and Dataframe** :

> A Dataset is a distributed collection of data.
>
> A DataFrame is a Dataset organized into named columns.
>   In the Scala API, DataFrame is simply a type alias of Dataset[Row].

---

> With a SparkSession, applications can create DataFrames from an existing RDD, from a Hive table, or from Spark data sources.

---

You have a csv file and you can simply create a dataframe by doing one of the following:

---

- **From your `spark-shell` using the `SparkSession` variable `spark`:**

  `val df = spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load("sample.csv")`

---

- **After reading the file into dataframe, you can register it into a temporary view.**

  `df.createOrReplaceTempView("foo")`

---

- **SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by Spark**

  `val fooDF = spark.sql("SELECT name, age FROM foo WHERE age BETWEEN 13 AND 19")`

---

- **You can also query that file directly with SQL:**

  `val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM csv.'file:///path to the file/'")`

---

- **Make sure that you run spark in local mode when you load data from local, or else you will get error. The error occurs when you have already set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable,and which expects `"hdfs://..."` otherwise `"file://"`.**
- **Set your spark.sql.warehouse.dir (default: ${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse).**

  `.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/path/to/my/")`

It is the default location of Hive warehouse directory (using Derby)
with managed databases and tables. Once you set the warehouse directory, Spark will be able to locate your files, and you can load csv.

Reference : [Spark SQL Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/sql-programming-guide.html)

Comment: I tried this line : val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("D://ResourceData.csv")

It throws some long error and when i execute df.show() it gives df was not found

Comment: I want to load data from local machine not from hdfs. Can you check at your end the working path pls

Comment: Updated with the required path info.

Comment: i am trying and is there any best tool in which i can use spark instead of playing it in cmd

Comment: One Google away : [here](https://spark.apache.org/developer-tools.html). Please consider to comment on the specific question related.

Comment: i tried this 
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("file:///D://ResourceData.csv") but throws an error

Comment: You have to configure warehouse directory in your `SparkSession`. Updated the answer.

Comment: how to set that i tried this code but it again throws an error 
scala> .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///D:/")
<console>:25: error: value config is not a member of org.apache.spark.SparkConte
xt

Comment: You can give the option in `spark-shell` using `--conf` or `-c`.  Or you could stop the current `SparkSession` and create a new one, then try `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/path/to/my/")`. Assuming that `spark` has your `SparkSession` .

Comment: I wasn't able to set and got this error: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client

Comment: But please let me know how you are running Spark ?Is it cloudera VM ?

Answer (score 0):

Spark version 2.2.0 has built-in support for csv.

> In your **spark-shell** run the following code
>
> ```
> val df= spark.read
>              .option("header","true")
>              .csv("D:/abc.csv")
>
> df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Team_Id: string, Team_Name: string ... 1 more field]
> ```

Comment: Okay i ll try this n ll let u know

Comment: I got this error 17/12/27 10:36:38 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1062)